# Producer-Consumer in Java for Airport Flights

Tags: java, producer-consumer

I have an array an 40 scheduled flights; each flight Object has stored data: flight number, airline, departure city, arrival city, flight time, flight length.

As each flight time happens, a **flight event generator thread** will change the status of each flight, from Scheduled, to Departed, to Delayed, to Arrived, and so forth. This part isn't the problem.

The producer-consumer aspect is as follows. As these events occur (departure, arrival, delay), the aforementioned flight event generator thread must publish these changes to an **airline thread**, one thread for each airline (specified by the flight Object: Southwest, American, etc.). Then, these airline threads will publish the changes to every **airport flight monitor thread**, one thread for each airport (again, specified by the flight Object). These threads, in turn, publish changes to a file.

My question is, how exactly should I handle this seemingly compound producer-consumer problem?  Also, how should I handle two flights with identical departure times?

Comment: Are you sure you need to use threads for this? Seems like rather than threads you might do just as well with a Flight, Airline, and AirportFlightMonitor object working together in a single thread.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, it is mandated that I use the described threads. Doesn't really seem that useful to me, but so be it.

Answer (score 2):

Usually in java to implement Producer/Consumer pattern use [`java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).

Take a look on [this](http://blog.ilandos.com/producer-consumer-blocking-queue) blog post.

Answer (score 0):

Go through these video tutorials on YouTube by caveofprogramming:

This is using a Blocking Queue which Java supports out of the box:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vrt5LqpH2D0&list=PLBB24CFB073F1048E

This is if you want to write our own synchronization logic using wait, notify, etc.:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gx_YUORX5vk&list=PLBB24CFB073F1048E

In fact, you should go through the entire series on Multithreading on his channel. Very nice tutorials.